# Launch File Highlighting in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering if anyone knows how to get eclipse to see .launch files as if they where XML and perform syntax highlighting based off the xml style?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61373/launch-file-highlighting-in-eclipse/) by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

1. install a XML editor plugin (search e.g. "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools")
2. configure File Associations (Window -> Preferences -> Gerneral -> Editors -> File Associations):
   Add "*.launch" and select the internal xml editor

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-04-23**:
Alternatively open the context menu on a file and choose *Open with* -> *XML editor*. I found eclipse to remember that in some way..

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-11-19**:
You can see the .launch file but you cannot debug it in eclipse. At least, I could not find any solution. I am not sure though.